# Can't access RAM from PCIe device

Tags: kernel, intel, pci, iommu

I use **Intel Xeon** with centos8 , kernel 4.18.

There is also an FPGA connected to CPU through PCIe.

The FPGA try to access RAM (through DMA) using physical address in RAM, but it fails in access.

1. using older PC (**Intel DUO**), with same OS, FPGA, etc - accessing RAM from FPGA is successful.
2. Install windows on the same PC - accessing RAM from FPGA is successful.
3. using `intel_iommu=off` in the PC - does not help, same problem.

What can cause this failure ? BIOS ? If so, why changing to windows solved it and why intel_iommu=off didn't help ?